# How to print out the execution time of each step easily in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

My script takes exceptionally long time to run. I think there must be something wrong. Hence, I wish to find out which line takes up much time. I need to print out how much time each line takes to run.

One rash solution in my mind is to encapsulate each line with

```
tic;
my_line_here;
fprint('line %d ', line_idx);
toc;
line_idx = line_idx+1;
```

However, I am reluctant to implement like this, as it is really exhausting for me to wrap EVERY line of a very long script. Is there a smarter way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Have you tried to use the [Profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)? That offers very detailed information...

Comment: This sounds like what [profiling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, profiler would probably do the trick. Your question specifically said you wanted to print/store each lines runtime, so I can give you a slightly better way to do so.

```
timeSet =[0];
initTic = tic;
foo;
timeSet{end+1} = toc(initTic) - timeSet(end);
bar;
timeSet{end+1} = toc(initTic) - timeSet(end);
```

You'll still have to insert the timeSet line after each section you want to measure, but it's just one standard line, so it's easy to copy-paste. I tried to answer the question in the bounds you set, so I hope this is useful to someone.